# Возможно ли употребление тире в этом предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Писала материал на заказ, в тексте была фраза

> Погружной тип блендера – самый практичный в использовании.

Заказчик попался принципиальный и очень возмущен использованием тире. Соглашусь, что оно скорее лишнее, но чувствую, что постановка данного знака препинания в предложении возможна. Но вот балда, все правила забыла. Подскажите, я заблуждаюсь или тире допустимо? Если допустимо, то на какое правило сослаться?

Comment: Если вам дан (или будет дан) исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 4):

По-моему, без тире это предложение невозможно публиковать.

Возможно, здесь играет роль то, что сказуемое выражено не отдельным прилагательным, а группой слов (на мой взгляд, сказуемое здесь — "самый практичный в использовании").

Но если говорить о сказуемом, выраженом прилагательным, то можно сослаться на логическое и интонационное членение предложения.

У Розенталя (в [§ 5. Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92#pp92)) находим:

> 10. Если сказуемое выражено прилагательным (в том числе местоименным) или предложно-именным сочетанием, тире перед сказуемым обычно не ставится: Погода несносная, дорога скверная, ямщик упрямый… (П.); Земля велика и прекрасна (Ч.); Вишнёвый сад мой! (Ч.); Небо без единого облачка; Люди здесь необыкновенной доброты.
>
> Тире перед сказуемым-прилагательным ставится:
>
> 1) при логическом или интонационном членении предложения: Зрачки — кошачьи, длинные (Ш.); Высота возле разбросанных домиков хутора — командная (Каз.);

Comment: Объяснение, скорее всего, именно такое. Но заказчик (если он грамотный), возможно хотел избежать логического (тем более интонационного) членения, т.е. не "ломать" предложение, а оставить ровным, нейтральным, что иногда звучит лучше стилистически.

Comment: @alexsms Что-то Вы не то сказали. Логическое членение — свойство предложения, а не способ расстановки знаков. "Избежать логического членения" означает изменить логику предложения.

Comment: Как я понял, логическое (интонационное) членение приведено у Розенталя в примерах. И там это художественный прием. В тексте про блендер, возможно, это и не нужно. Логическое членение - термин не уточнял пока (но я его понял, как "дополнительное" членение для усиления).

Comment: Apropos, но лично я бы поставил тире (по-моему, с ним лучше). Странно, что заказчик был "возмущён" (но не сказано, в чем точная причина возмущения, т.е. сам заказчик читал ли правила или просто "принципиальный" из принципа).